# Rudin: Relating $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^n e^{-x} = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{-n} \log(x) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

On page 182 of Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Third Edition," Rudin states that one can use the fact that

(1) $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^n e^{-x} = 0$ for every integer $n$

to prove that

(2) $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{-n} \log(x) = 0$ for every integer $n$.

Is there a slick way to see this that doesn't eventually boil down to using

$$\log(x) = \int_1^x \frac{dx}{x},$$

which is how Rudin initially proves (2)?

Indeed, (1) implies that you can't use the comparison test to prove (2), since

$x^{2n} e^{-x} < \log(x)$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Sadly, I am therefore at a loss, and am thus asking for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is true: Substitute $x=e^u$ in (2) so
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} x^{-\alpha}\ln x
=\lim_{u\to\infty} ue^{-\alpha u}
=\Big(\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^\frac{1}{\alpha} e^{- x}\Big)^{\alpha}
<\Big(\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^n e^{- x}\Big)^{\alpha}\to0
$$
because for every $\alpha$ real there exist integer n that $\dfrac{1}{\alpha}<n$.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, thank you!